# Was boost::bool_testable<> relocated or removed?

Tags: c++, boost, safe-bool-idiom

I'm trying to leverage `boost::bool_testable<>` (from Boost.Operators) to implement the safe bool idiom for a class, but the most recent version of the library (1.49 as of this post) doesn't seem to have it anymore.

Where did it go? Is there a better alternative available now, and I've just missed it?

I'm not able to use C++11 and therefore cannot use the language extensions that render safe bool unnecessary.

Comment: According to my searching `bool_testable` was added, but then removed shortly after and never existed in a release ([reference](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/operator-safe-bool-td2617427.html)). In what version of boost did you see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a late answer, but I'm only active on Stack Overflow for a short time and I just found your question. I am the maintainer of Boost.Operators and I [removed](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/94644) `bool_testable` back in December 2003 before it could accidentially be released.

Sam Partington proposed it a few weeks earlier and I added it to the CVS repository. It looked promising in the beginning, but soon problems showed up in certain scenarious.

The *main* problem, IIRC, for a class `T` derived from `boost::bool_testable<T>` had to do with conversion detection. A class which is convertible to `bool`, but not to `int`, should yield `boost::is_convertible<T,int>::value == false`, but instead, it became ambiguous and you ended up with a compile failure.

There were also other issues and solving one of them usually implied breaking another. One example involved types where the user wanted explicit conversion to `bool` *and* his own `operator int()`.

So, long story short, we never figured out how to make it robust enough. In case of doubt, the benefit was too small (safe ~5 lines of copy-paste code) compared with the potential problems, that I decided to play it safe and hence I removed it.

After it was removed, the issue never came up again and people eventually started to either copy-paste the Safe-Bool-Idiom code to their classes, or (some time later) they started to use `explicit operator bool()` as it became available.

That said, it's best if you just copy the lines manually. I know it's not an elegant solution and I don't like copy-paste either, but the alternatives were all worse than that.

Comment: I guess that's that then. A great answer justifying its removal. Thanks!

Comment: Since it is almost 10 years after the events you described and C++ has evolved, do you think the idiom could be reintroduced in a safe & robust way today?

Comment: @CygnusX1 There is no need to re-introduce any idiom as we have `explicit operator bool()` now. Or if you will, that *is* the "new" Safe-Bool-Idiom.