# Safe bool idiom in boost?

Tags: c++, boost, safe-bool-idiom

Does the boost library provide an implementation of a safe bool idiom, so that I could derive my class from it?

If yes - where is it?

If no - what are my alternatives beyond implementing it myself?

---

I found the following similar question: " [Is there a safe bool idiom helper in boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883901/is-there-a-safe-bool-idiom-helper-in-boost) " and the accepted answer suggests using `bool_testable<>` in [Boost.Operators](http://www.pdc.kth.se/training/Talks/C++/boost/libs/utility/operators.htm).

Unfortunately, when I checked the [boost manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) I couldn't find it there. Code using it fails to compile too.

I also stumbled on another SO question " [Was boost::bool_testable<> relocated or removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490675/was-boostbool-testable-relocated-or-removed) " and the comment there suggests that the `bool_testable` actually never made to any release version of the boost.

There is also an interesting [article by Bjorn Karlsson](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) on the subject which contains a code which could be copy-pasted into my project. I am hoping however, that there is a commonly accepted and maintained utility library (e.g. boost) that implements that already.

---

For compatibility reasons, I do not want to rely on C++11.

Comment: Have you considered solving the problem by not implicitly converting to `bool`?

Comment: There's a re-usable Safe Bool implementation on page 3 of this article: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention it, but I did see that and I might copy-paste that code, but I was hoping that some commonly accepted and maintained utility library (boost comes first in mind) already does that.

Comment: You might be interested in the update of " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490675/was-boostbool-testable-relocated-or-removed "

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not know of a commonly accepted utility library that provides the safe-bool idiom.  There have been a few attempts within Boost, and they often result in debates about how to provide a safe-bool implementation (naming conventions, macros, inline includes, inheritance).  As a result, there are at least three implementations existing within Boost, with only one of the implementations, [Boost.Spirit.Classic's safe_bool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/safe_bool.hpp),  designed for external use.

---

Details and concepts for each implementation:

- [Boost.Range's safe_bool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/range/detail/safe_bool.hpp)

  - Contained within the *detail* directory, so not explicitly designed for external use.
  - Implemented by using a template helper type and static member functions.
  - The safe-bool enabled class is expected to:

    - Provide an `operator boost::range_detail::safe_bool< MemberPtr >::unspecified_bool_type() const` member function that delegates to the static `safe_bool::to_unspecified_bool()` function.
- [Boost.SmartPtr's operator_bool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp):

  - Contained within the *detail* directory, so not explicitly designed for external use.
  - The header file is intended to be included directly within a class definition.  See [shared_ptr.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) for an example.
  - Requires including `boost/detail/workaround.hpp` before including `smart_ptr/detail/operator.hpp`.
  - The surrounding safe-bool enabled class is expected to:

    - Provide a `this_type` type.
    - Provide a `T` type.
    - Provide a `T* px` member variable.
- [Boost.Spirit.Classic's safe_bool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/safe_bool.hpp)

  - Designed for external use.
  - Uses the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern.
  - Designed to support base class chaining, allowing `boost::spirit::class::safe_bool` to be used without mandating multiple inheritance on the derived class.
  - The safe-bool enabled class is expected to:

    - Publicly derive from `boost::spirit::classic::safe_bool< Derived >`.  If `Derived` already inherits from `Base`, then use `boost::spirit::classic::safe_bool< Derived, Base >`.
    - Provide a `bool operator_bool() const` member function.

---

This example uses Boost 1.50.  Each class should evaluate to true in boolean context if the integer passed to the constructor is greater than 0:

```
// Safe-bool idiom with Boost.Range.
#include <boost/range/detail/safe_bool.hpp>
class range_bool
{
public:
  range_bool( int x ) : x_( x ) {}
private:
  // None of these are required, but makes the implementation cleaner.
  typedef boost::range_detail::safe_bool< int range_bool::* > safe_bool_t;
  typedef safe_bool_t::unspecified_bool_type unspecified_bool_type;
  int dummy;
public:
  operator unspecified_bool_type() const
  {
    return safe_bool_t::to_unspecified_bool( x_ > 0, &range_bool::dummy );
  }
private:
  int x_;
};

// Safe-bool idiom with Boost.SmartPtr.
#include <boost/detail/workaround.hpp>
class smart_ptr_bool
{
public:
  smart_ptr_bool( int x ) { px = ( x > 0 ) ? &dummy : 0 ; }
private:
  typedef smart_ptr_bool this_type; // -.
  typedef int T;                    //   :- Required concepts when using
  T* px;                            // -'   smart_ptr's operator_bool.
private:
  T dummy; // Simple helper.
public:
  #include <boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp>
};

// Safe-bool idiom with Boost.Spirit.
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_safe_bool.hpp>
class spirit_bool: public boost::spirit::classic::safe_bool< spirit_bool >
{
public:
  spirit_bool( int x ) : x_( x ) {} 
public:
  // bool operator_bool() is required by the spirit's safe_bool CRTP.
  bool operator_bool() const { return x_ > 0; }
private:
  int x_;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "range_bool( -1 ):     " << range_bool( -1 )     << std::endl
            << "range_bool(  1 ):     " << range_bool(  1 )     << std::endl
            << "smart_ptr_bool( -1 ): " << smart_ptr_bool( -1 ) << std::endl
            << "smart_ptr_bool(  1 ): " << smart_ptr_bool(  1 ) << std::endl
            << "spirit_bool( -1 ):    " << spirit_bool( -1 )    << std::endl
            << "spirit_bool(  1 ):    " << spirit_bool(  1 )    << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Resulting output:

```
range_bool( -1 ):     0
range_bool(  1 ):     1
smart_ptr_bool( -1 ): 0
smart_ptr_bool(  1 ): 1
spirit_bool( -1 ):    0
spirit_bool(  1 ):    1
```

---

I do not know of any alternatives.  When I have ran across safe-bool idioms, most of the implementations have been a copy-and-paste variants of the implementation provided in [Bjorn Karlsson's article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since Boost 1.55 there is `<boost/core/explicit_operator_bool.hpp>` header in Boost.Core. It requires from you to define `bool operator!()` and use `BOOST_EXPLICIT_OPERATOR_BOOL()` macro (there are also variants of it `BOOST_EXPLICIT_OPERATOR_BOOL_NOEXCEPT()` and `BOOST_CONSTEXPR_EXPLICIT_OPERATOR_BOOL()`).

[The documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/explicit_operator_bool.html) has an example:

```
template< typename T >
class my_ptr
{
    T* m_p;

public:
    BOOST_EXPLICIT_OPERATOR_BOOL()

    bool operator!() const
    {
        return !m_p;
    }
};
```