# Is it dangerous to overload bool operator in this case

Tags: c++, casting, boolean, operator-overloading

I have seen comments or answers on SoF stating that overloading the cast operator to bool is dangerous and I should prefer the `void* operator` instead. Still I would like to ask if it is dangerous practice to use this operator in my use case and if yes why.

I implement a simply geometry library and one of its most basic classes is a point that I define in the following way:

```
struct point {
  double x, y;
  bool real;
  point(double x_, double y_): x(x_), y(y_), real(true) {}
  point(): x(0), y(0), real(true) {}

  operator bool() {
    return real;
  }
};
```

I will try to explain why I need the cast operator to bool. I have another class called line and I have a function declared as follows:

```
point intersect(const line& a, const line& b);
```

Now having overloaded the cast operator to bool of a point I can write both: `point p = intersect(a,b);` and `if (intersect(a,b))` thus either getting the intersection point of two lines or checking if two lines intersect. I use this in other places as well but I believe this example is enough to show the usage of the cast operator. Is my usage of the cast operator dangerous and if it is could you please give an example when the effect will not be as expected?

EDIT: one small addition thanks to juanchopanza : in this project I am limited to not using c++11, so I can not make the operator explicit.

Comment: If you have C++11, you can remove danger by making the cast operator `explicit`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know but I am limited to pre-`c++11`

Comment: If you cannot be bothered to implement your own `safe_bool`, see this answer for a set available in boost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781584/safe-bool-idiom-in-boost

Comment: The others answered why the cast to bool is a bad idea. I'll also say: The design is pretty flawed. Your struct is 4 byte larger than required, it contains a non-canonical member that is only required for one operation. Instead: Return an optional from intersect, or implement `bool intersects()` predicate.

Comment: There is no **cast** operator. This is a **conversion** operator.

Comment: Concerns about inadvertent conversions tend to be greatly overblown. What danger are you concerned about? That someone might write `int x = intersect(a,b)` and think that it actually does something useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not good enough. Since you're stuck with C++03, [safe-bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool) is what you should be using if you need such a thing at all (otherwise, `explicit` conversion function should be preferred).

An alternative solution is to return `boost:optional` instead:

```
boost::optional<point> intersect(const line& a, const line& b);
```

I would adopt this approach (even in C++11), as it looks semantically better — parallel lines don't have intersection point, so the  return value should indeed be *optional* (or *maybe* value).

Comment: I think that thanks to the link in your answer I understand why overloading bool is dangerous. But will `void*` be better in that sense?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Please go through the link and understand why it is called *safe* bool idiom.

Comment: I can't seem to understand why implementing safe bool idiom as proposed makes an attempt to write `p1 < p2` where both objects are of the same type. I verified compilation fails, but I don't understand **why**

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: because function pointers (or what's relevant here: pointers-to-member-function) aren't `<`-comparable.

Comment: @SteveJessop ahhh that's what I missed. I did not know that. I was wondering why do we use a function pointer not a simple pointer. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it true that even if I adopt this way of implementing a safe bool, if I write `!(a == b)` it will compile and evaluate to true? http://ideone.com/pNNczF Is there a way to fix that behavior?

Comment: @Nawaz you need to perform a few more fixes. Note the signature of the comparison operators - you should remove the first parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is dangerous. Just for example, let's consider your `point` exactly as-is, with no definition of `operator+`. Despite that lack, if we try to add two `point` objects, the compiler won't object at all:

```
point a, b;

std::cout << a + b;
```

This works by converting each `point` to `bool`, then adding the `bool`s. In an integer context, `false` converts to 0 and `true` converts to 1, so we can expect the code above to print out 2. Of course, I've just used addition as an example. You could just as well do subtraction, multiplication, division, bitwise operations, logical operations, etc. All of them will compile and execute, but obviously produce worthless results. Likewise, if we pass a `point` to some function that only accepts a numeric type, the compiler won't stop s or complain -- it'll just convert to `bool`, and the function will get either `0` or `1` depending on whether `real` was true or not.

The safe-bool idiom is safe (well, less dangerous anyway) because you can test a `void *` in a Boolean context, but a `void *` won't implicitly convert to much of anything else like `bool` will. You (mostly<sup>1</sup>) can't accidentally do arithmetic, bitwise operations, etc., on them.

---

<sub>1. There are a *few* holes anyway, mostly involving calling something else that does some sort of explicit conversion on the `void *`. Being able to mark conversion operators `explicit` is better, but honestly they give a lot more improvement in readability than safety.</sub>

Comment: You're assuming safe-bool idiom uses `void*`?

Comment: @Nawaz: There are a number of different things that have been called by that name over the years, some using conversion to `void *`, some overloading comparison to `bool`, a few doing even stranger things. Conversion to `void *` is probably the most common though.

Comment: The link in Nawaz's answer gives an example why not to use `void*`. `a < b` would be valid with possible undefined behavior. I was also surprised that you called this the "safe bool idiom".

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, as I said: `explicit` really is better. In all honesty, however, actual instances of misbehavior from a conversion to `void *` seem to be pretty rare in practice, even though it's easy to come up with a half dozen (or so) ways it *could* lead to a problem.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: well, examples are non-existent in well-tested code, same as any other error ;-) Static type checks are not *necessary*, but since C++ has them you try not to trample all over them. The weird thing is just that what you call "safe bool idiom" but then say has some holes, is exactly what Nawaz and I think was the motivation for inventing what we call "safe bool idiom". All previous efforts including `void*` being "unsafe" to varying degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Strange that those people didn't tell you *why* overloading `operator bool()` is dangerous.

The reason is that C++ has implicit conversion from `bool` to all other numeric types. So if you overload `operator bool()` then you lose a lot of type checks that users of the class would normally expect. They can supply a `point` anywhere that an `int` or `float` is expected.

Overloading `operator void*()` is less dangerous because there's less that `void*` converts to, but still has the same fundamental issue that the `void*` type is used for other things.

The idea of the safe bool idiom is to return a pointer type that doesn't convert to *anything* used in any API.

Note that there would be no need to worry about this if you were willing to write `if (intersect(a,b).real)`, or perhaps `if (intersect(a,b).exists())`. C++03 *does* have explicit conversions. Any function with one parameter (or non-static member function with no parameters) is a conversion of sorts. C++03 just doesn't have explicit conversion *operators*.

Comment: I still don't like the idea of `real` or `exists()`. `optional<point>` or `maybe<point>` would be better.

Comment: @Nawaz: sure, in this case it's strange to define a type that represents something that may or may not actually be a point. But just generally, if you're going to have an object that might be in an error state, I think people are over-committed to the idea that you should be able to test that state by bunging the object in boolean context. You're allowed to decide that's just too much hassle to implement :-) If you're up for extending the Euclidean plane, then you could make it `intersect(a,b).isfinite()`.

Answer (score 1):

You might run into all kind of trouble due to implicit conversions from bool to a numeric value.
Also, your line class got an (in my point of vew) dangerious member 'bool real', to carry results of function calls. An intersection function returning an intersection value or NaN if the lines do not intersect could resolve your problem.

Example

Having a (infinite) line class holding an origin p and a vector v:

```
struct Line {
    Point p;
    Vector v;

    Point operator () (double r) const {
        return p + r * v;
    }
};
```

And a function calculating an intersection value

```
/// A factor suitable to be passed to line a as argument to calculate the
/// inersection point.
/// - A value in the range [0, 1] indicates a point between
///   a.p and a.p + a.v.
/// - The result is NaN if the lines do not intersect. 
double intersection(const Line& a, const Line& b) {
    double d = a.v.x * b.v.y - a.v.y * b.v.x;
    if( ! d) return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    else {
        double n = (b.p.x - a.p.x) * b.v.y
                 - (b.p.y - a.p.y) * b.v.x;
        return n/d;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
double d = intersection(a, b);
if(d == d) { // std::isnan is c++11
    Point p = a(d);
}
```

Or

```
if(0 <= d && d <= 1) {
    Point p = a(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, early in the C++ 2003 Standard class std::basic_ios had the following conversion operator

```
operator void*() const
```

Now as the new C++ Standard has keyword explicit this operator was substituted for

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

So if you will add keyword explicit for your operator I think it will not be dangerous.:)

The other way is to define operator bool operator !() instead of the conversion operator.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are already a few very good answers I would like to assemble a bit more complete answer with explanation of why the proposed solution does work.

1.Why is my solution wrong?
The compiler performs implicit conversions from bool to numeric types resulting in unexpected operators being defined. For instance:

```
point p;
if (p < 1)
```

Will compile while I did not expect it to. Changing the operator for conversion to `operator void*()` will improve the things but only slightly as there some operators(although less than for bool) that are defined for `void *` and their existence will result again in unexpected behavior.

2.So what is the correct solution. The correct solution can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=More_C%2b%2b_Idioms/Safe_bool). But I will include the code for my class so that I can explain why it works and why do we solve the problem in this way:

```
class point {
  typedef void (point::*bool_type)() const;
  void not_supported() const; // NOTE: only declaration NO body!

public:
  double x, y;
  bool real;
  point(double x_, double y_): x(x_), y(y_), real(true) {}
  point(): x(0), y(0), real(true) {}

  operator bool_type() {
    return (real == true)? &point::not_supported : 0;
  }

  template<typename T>
  bool operator==(const T& rhs) const {
    not_supported();
    return false;
  }

  template<typename T>
  bool operator!=(const T& rhs) const {
    not_supported();
    return false;
  }
};
```

Now first I will explain why do we have to use a type that is a function pointer and not a plain pointer. The answer is stated by Steve Jessop in a comment below Nawaz's answer. `function pointers are not < comparable`, thus any attempt to write `p < 5` or any other comparison between a point and some other type will fail to compile.

Why do we need to have an method with no body (`not_supported`)? Because in this way each time we try to instantiate the templated methods for comparison(that is `==` and `!=`), we will have a function call of a method with no body that will cause a compile error.

Comment: Your `point` class should support `==` operator because a point class should be comparable with other points. And the implementation of `operator==` in the wiki page, has nothing to do with safe-bool idiom per se. It is just to demonstrate that safe-bool idiom doesn't convert into `bool` or something which can be compared.

Comment: If I do not overload == I was able to compare my class to another class with similar structure with no compilation error. I tried this.

Comment: I didn't say that. I said your class should support `==`. Here is what I meant : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb22e2a0baaed5f2

Comment: In fact I don't **have to** overload this operator. And what is more important even if I do I will never implement it the way you do, as strict comparison of doubles is not a good idea