# How can I overload empty operator of struct?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I want to overload a function to check if a struct object is empty.

Here is my struct definition:

```
struct Bit128 {
    unsigned __int64 H64;
    unsigned __int64 L64;

    bool operate(what should be here?)(const Bit128 other) {
        return H64 > 0 || L64 > 0;
    }
}
```

This is test code:

```
Bit128 bit128;
bit128.H64 = 0;
bit128.L64 = 0;
if (bit128)
    // error
bit128.L64 = 1
if (!bit128)
    // error
```

Comment: Look up `operator bool()`.   As a member function that takes no arguments.

Comment: [c] doesn't have methods in structs, or otherwise, please tag your questions accordingly from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <cstdint>
struct Bit128 
{
    std::uint64_t H64;
    std::uint64_t L64;
    explicit operator bool () const {
        return H64 > 0u || L64 > 0u;
    }
};
```

Comment: This should be [`explicit operator bool()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242768/7571258) unless OP doesn't have C++11 available in which case the `safe bool` idiom should be used, e. g. one of these [boost implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854479/7571258).

Comment: @zett42: Would be safer, yes.

Answer (score 4):

You want to overload the `bool` operator:

```
explicit operator bool() const {
 // ...
```

This operator doesn't have to be, but should be, a `const` method.

Comment: Why `explicit` if the OP's use case has an implicit conversion desired?

Comment: @AndyG Because `explicit operator bool` can be used in places where it can be [contextually converted to bool](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39995574/7571258). This is still more restrictive than implicit conversion so it should be the default way of declaring `operator bool`.

Comment: @zett42: I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no "empty" operator, but if you want the object to have a significance in boolean contexts (such as if-conditions), you want to overload the boolean conversion operator:

```
explicit operator bool() const {
  return H64 != 0 || L64 != 0;
}
```

Note that the explicit conversion operator requires C++11. Before that, you can use a non-explicit operator, but it comes with many downsides. Instead you'll want to google for the safe-bool idiom.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are looking for is `explicit operator bool() const` which [is safe in c++11 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11)